# Blazored Typeahead import value selected from database

Tags: blazor, typeahead, blazored

How do i set the selected value in the product list when editing?

> ```
> <Blazored.Typeahead.BlazoredTypeahead SearchMethod="RicercaCategoria" 
>                                       @bind-Value="categoriaSelezionato" 
>                                       EnableDropDown="false" 
>                                       Placeholder="Scegli o aggiungi la Categoria">
>     <SelectedTemplate>@context.NomeCategoria</SelectedTemplate>
>     <ResultTemplate>@context.NomeCategoria</ResultTemplate>
> </Blazored.Typeahead.BlazoredTypeahead>
> ```

From a list  I get the categories to see.
From a database instead I recover the record that interests me

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I have implemented the code with your suggestions, I noticed that it loads the category but it doesn't show.
To view it on the screen, I have to press on the Typehead and press the ESC key on the keyboard.

it's incredible!

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup an event to do that. You have to modify your syntax slightly as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/Blazored/Typeahead#subscribing-to-changes-in-selected-values):

Replace your @bind-Value with (guessing at class names):

```
Value="categoriaSelezionato"
ValueChanged="@( (Categoria c) => SelectedCategoriaChanged(c) )"
ValueExpression="@( () => categoriaSelezionato )"
```

You may also need TValue and TItem, but I did not.

Then handle the event:

```
private void SelectedCategoriaChanged(Categoria categoria )
{
     // Use the selected record however needed


     // Set your Value so it shows:
     categoriaSelezionato = categoria;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I have implemented the code with your suggestions, I noticed that it loads the category but it doesn't show.
To view it on the screen, I have to press on the Typehead and press the ESC key on the keyboard.

it's incredible!

Can you help me?

Comment: You need to manually set `categoriaSelezionato` inside the event handler. See my edit.